# How to handle a redis connection error in express?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have an express database that connects to multiple redis servers by receiving the connection ip from a client.

It works fine if the redis database exists. The problem im facing is that if the ip doesnt exist, I will receive a

> Error: Error: Redis connection to xxxx failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
> xxx

Being this totally understandable, but the problem is that my connection object is still defined. And i cant really seem how to identify this object as a failed connection.
The only hint i might have might be in the `connection._events.error` variable, but it returns a `[Function]`

This is my code

```
let connections = []

const killRedis = (redisClient, ip, port) => {
    redisClient.quit()
    connections = connections.filter((i) => { return i.ip !== ip && i.port != port })
}

const subscribe = (redisClient, url, port) => {
    redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
        //this is supposed to handle the error, but i dont know how to make the "undefined" value available for the createRedisClient function. Since this seems to be delayed
        killRedis(redisClient, url, port)
        return undefined;
    });
    redisClient.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('Connected to Redis');
        return redisClient;
    });
}

findConnection = (ip, port) => {
    let connection = connections.filter(i => i.ip == ip && i.port == port)

    if (connection && connection.length > 0) {

        return connection[0].connection
    } else {
        connections.push({
            ip: ip,
            port: port,
            connection: require('redis').createClient(port, ip, {
                no_ready_check: true,
                db: 1
            })
        })
        let pushedConnection = connections.filter(i => i.ip == ip && i.port == port)[0].connection
        subscribe(pushedConnection, ip, port)
        return pushedConnection
    }
}
const createRedisClient = async (port, url) => {
    let redisClient = findConnection(url, port)
    console.log(redisClient._events.error) //[Function]
    return redisClient // this is always a connection object, even if the connection is faulty
}
module.exports = { createRedisClient }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection status is not known then `findConnection` returns, because node-redis is [asynchronous, it uses callbacks](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis). One solution would be to promisify your `subscribe` function, like this:

```
const subscribe = (redisClient, url, port) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        killRedis(redisClient, url, port)
        reject(err)
    });
    redisClient.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('Connected to Redis');
        resolve(redisClient)
    });
})
```

Then, in the `findConnection`, you just handle the possible rejections with a `try-catch` block. Note that it's been marked `async`:

```
findConnection = async (ip, port) =>  {
    let connection = connections.filter(i => i.ip == ip && i.port == port)

    if (connection && connection.length > 0) {

        return connection[0].connection
    } else {
        connections.push({
            ip: ip,
            port: port,
            connection: require('redis').createClient(port, ip, {
                no_ready_check: true,
                db: 1
            })
        })
        let pushedConnection = connections.filter(i => i.ip == ip && i.port == port)[0].connection
        try {
            const client = await subscribe(pushedConnection, ip, port)
            return client
        } catch (error) {
            return undefined // not sure what you want to do with rejections
        }
    }
```

Then, finally (also `async`):

```
const createRedisClient = async (port, url) => {
    let redisClient = await findConnection(url, port)
    console.log(redisClient)
    return redisClient // this is undefined if there was an error connecting 
}
```

Instead of `async-await`, you could always use `then-catch`, etc. Also, I believe the `error` callback will be called on every error. That is, in case of a successful connection, if you encounter any redis errors later on, `killRedis` will still be called. If it's intended, alright. Otherwise, you may want to refactor your logic so that connections are only registered when they have successfully been made.